# How to find the mean value of a array column and then subtract the mean from each element in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Here is the list: This is a dataframe in pyspark

| id | list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [10, 20, 30] | [30, 40, 50] |
| 2 | [35, 65, 85] | [15, 5, 45] |

This is the desired output. Calculate the mean of each list and subtract the mean value from each element in the list. I'm using pyspark for this.

| id | list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [10-mean, 20-mean, 30-mean] | [30-mean, 40-mean, 50-mean] |
| 2 | [35-mean, 65-mean, 85-mean] | [15-mean, 5-mean, 45-mean] |

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate) to calculate the mean value for each list, then using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) functions on the array columns to subtract the mean for each element :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("list1_avg", F.expr("aggregate(list1, bigint(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc / size(list1))")) \
    .withColumn("list2_avg", F.expr("aggregate(list2, bigint(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc / size(list2))")) \
    .withColumn("list1", F.expr("transform(list1, x -> x - list1_avg)")) \
    .withColumn("list2", F.expr("transform(list2, x -> x - list2_avg)")) \
    .drop("list1_avg", "list2_avg")

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
#|id |list1                                                        |list2                                                        |
#+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
#|1  |[-10.0, 0.0, 10.0]                                           |[-10.0, 0.0, 10.0]                                           |
#|2  |[-26.666666666666664, 3.3333333333333357, 23.333333333333336]|[-6.666666666666668, -16.666666666666668, 23.333333333333332]|
#+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```